# Anime or animation about giant ape vs asian dragons

Tags: story-identification, anime

I saw this when I was a kid, about 10 years ago, what I remember is that a great ape was tearing a dragon in two by holding it above the apes head, and pulling hard to separate it into two parts.

Comment: dragon ball? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2wsxdAuK-No

Comment: While the users on this site have done miracles in the past, this question could be improved by looking at [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335) and [How to ask a good (anime/manga) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874) and [edit]ing in some more details